# Sum of arrray with duplicate key values php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I array like this, now i want to sum of fee with same **originator** name.

and make a new array using that, so there is 3 cima haves here I need one array of that where `fee_potetial` is sum of all other where the originator is cima haves.

`$formEntries` returns values like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 54
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 100
            [originator] => cima haves

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 55
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 600
            [originator] => steve

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 56
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 500
            [originator] => cima haves

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 57
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 500
            [originator] =>  cima haves

        )

)
```

Here is code I was trying for isolation:

```
$originator = array_column($formEntries, 'originator');
$originator = array_unique($originator);
$array_filter = array_filter($formEntries, function ($key, $value) use ($originator) {
    return in_array($value, array_keys($originator));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

**I need output [fee_potential] => 1100 is sum**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 54
                [0] => 1
                [fee_potential] => 1100
                [originator] => cima haves

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 55
                [0] => 1
                [fee_potential] => 600
                [originator] => steve

            )
    )
```

Comment: So what output does your code generate

Comment: its just finds unique array but not giving me sum of fee_potential

Comment: Do you really want `entry_id` and `[0]` in the result array. They dont mean much as they stand

Comment: If you need to "group by" originator and "sum" all fee_potential of that criteria, you should use array_reduce instead: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: i dont really care for entry_id and 0

Comment: Where did the data come from? where is it going? It would be stupid to do this in PHP if you are reading the data from a relational database or writing it there.

Comment: the data is not straight forward in columns in database its in meta_data of wordpress table so query is not possible so must do in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple foreach loop would do it quite simply

```
$totals = [];

foreach( $formEntries as $entry) {
    if( isset($totals[$entry['originator']]){
        $totals[$entry['originator']]['fee_potential'] += $entry['fee_potential'];
    } else {
        $totals[$entry['originator']]['fee_potential'] = $entry['fee_potential'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution (pretty much we were thinking the same thing). However, it won't contain values for `entry_id` and `0`.

Comment: Ha seems `Great Minds think alike` but OP said he was not interested in those fields in a comment

Comment: Ohh. Missed that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just try looping through all elements like this

```
$final_arr = array();
foreach($formEntries as $value){
    if(isset($final_arr[$value['originator']])){
        $final_arr[$value['originator']]['fee_potential'] += $value['fee_potential'];
    }
    else{
        $final_arr[$value['originator']] = $value;
    }

}
```

It will check if an `originator` is already there in the final array. If it does, it will sum the value, else it will assign that array along with `fee_potential`.

Comment: Not a big fan of un braced IF statements. A real pain if you ever need to identify IF's in a find and replace kind of global edit

Comment: I use it only when there is one line of code in a IF block. Besides, I never had to identify IFs.

Comment: Well of course thats the only time you can use it. But https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: Heh. Thanks for the link. I faced that problem when I had to comment that line of code and write another.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working well Tested.

```
$result = array();
foreach($formEntries as $key => $v){
   if(in_array($v['originator'], array_column($result, 'originator'))){
      $result[array_search($v['originator'], array_column($result, 'originator'))]['fee_potential'] += $v['fee_potential'];
   }else{
      $result[$key] = $v;
   }
}
```

Result:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 54
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 1100
            [originator] => cima haves

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [entry_id] => 55
            [0] => 1
            [fee_potential] => 600
            [originator] => steve

        )
)
```